# Subtraction In Quadrature?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation

I have a system of particles (electrons) with an initial RMS energy spread (say "1"). It goes through a section of constant magnetic field (bend magnet) and the electrons radiate.

The electrons lose energy as a whole and the we have the final RMS energy spread (say "0.5").

Would it be correct to assume that in order to find the RMS energy change due to the radiating particles, we can subtract in quadrature the initial and final RMS energy spreads?

For example:

((1)^2)-((0.5)^2)=((radiation)^2)

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Are these dispersions in absolute energy units about some mean value? Doesn't the mean value of the energy change as well as the dispersion?

Comment: @ user1886681 Just a suggestion. I am not dealing currently with particles that radiate inside a field (they don't necessarily do this), but I just suggest a line of thinking. If you say that the electron radiates, you need the distribution P(E) of the electron energies, and the distribution P(e|E) of obtaining a photon energy e given that the electron energy is E. Now, if the initial beam of electrons is described by a wave-function, the radiation decoheres this wave-function because each electron gets coupled with the photon(s) that it emits. (see continuation)

Comment: (continuation)  That simplifies the life, you can treat the emitted photon(s) as being in a mixture state. (Am I clear?) Now, $P(e) = \sum P(E) P(e|E)$. Once you get the formula of P(e), (hopefully), the calculus of the mean value, RMS, whatever you want, is possible (but I don't know if it is simple). However, from what I said here, someone may derive a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

I am just trying to answer your question. I understand that you expect an answer of "yes" or "no". I am not sure if I'll succeed.

I start from the formula in my comment.

The variance for the initial electron energy is $$<(E - \ E_0)^2> = \Sigma_E P_{initial}(E) \ E^2 - [\Sigma_E P_{initial}(E) \ E]^2 . $$

The variance for the final electron energy is

$$<[(E - \ e) \ - <(E - \ e)>]^2> \ = \ <(E - \ e)^2> - <(E - \ e)>^2$$
$$= \Sigma_E P_{final}(E) \ E^2 - [\Sigma_E P_{final}(E) \ E]^2 $$

Now, the connection between the initial and final distribution of electron energies is given by $$P_{final} (E) = ∑_e \ P_{initial}(E+e)P(E|e+E)$$ where the conditioned probability $P(E|e+E) = P(e|e+E)$.

Introducing this in the previous equality and changing variable $E+e \ -> E$,
$$<(E \ - <E>)^2>_{final} \ = \Sigma_E P_{initial}(E) \ (E - e)^2P(e|E) \ - <E>_{final}^2$$

This is the relation that I was able to get, and it doesn't make impression that the simple subtraction that you propose, could be correct.